# Modify GUI from object created inside the gui in c++

Tags: java, c++, qt, oop, user-interface

I would like to ask about how can I add some text on the screen.
I have button, when I click on that, I create new object. It has a function which provide some data for me. 
How can I acces that data from the gui? I cannot have a getter because it gives me data after some time(after connection to the server). 
Is there possibilit to put text to textEdit within the object created inside of gui class?

thanks

I adding the code, explaining a little more, sry for confusing, thx for trying to help:

I have EchoClient object created inside of gui class:

```
void Comunication::startListening(){

    if (this->client == NULL)
       {
           this->client = new EchoClient(QUrl(QStringLiteral("ws://localhost:1234")), 0);
           QObject::connect(client, &EchoClient::closed, this,  &QApplication::quit);

    }
       else
           qWarning() << "Carefull, the client is already running";
   }
```

then in my EchoClient i have function

```
  void EchoClient::onTextMessageReceived(QString message)
{
    if (!m_debug)
        qDebug() << "Message received:" << message;
```

**HERE I would like to change the ui stuff.**

```
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more precise ? I can't help you since I have no valuable information to do so.
Access the data from the GUI ? What do you mean ?
Can you please provide some code too please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with a getter and setter and another button

**First button:** start listening...creates EchoClient object, this opens the websocket, connects to websocket server. In case the message has arrived from server it goes to method from EchoClient class called onTextMessageRecieved, there it sets atribute message to the value of incoming message.

```
void EchoClient::onTextMessageReceived(QString message)
{
    if (!m_debug)
        qDebug() << "Message received:" << message;

    setData(message); //setting atribute message
}
```

**Second button:** get data... this will call get method from EchoClient class. Comunication is my gui class.

```
void Comunication::on_getData_clicked()
{
    ui->textEdit_2->setText(this->client->getData());
}
```

But this solution is not good enough, could yo please advice how to make it that as soon as there is new message my textEdit will be automaticly updated? 
Should I do it in another thread? I dont have much experiences.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `setData()` emit a signal with the message.
If the `Communication` class has no access to the UI either, then just add the same signal there and make it forward the one from `EchoClient` (signal/signal connection).
At some place you will then have access the UI element and the "data source", so you can then connect the signal to an UI slot, e.g. `QTextEdit::append()`

Comment: Comunication is the gui class, how can I emit the signal with message? I dont know how to put those 2 together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. But your question at the moment seems too broad or unclear [at least] to me. I assume that you're using Qt Creator with its designer. So you should be able to access a `ui` object (in your `MainWindow` class). Having this object in hand you can change UI at anytime and at anywhere.

So, first assign that text box (i.e. `QLineEdit`) an id (for example `myLineEdit`). Now, `ui->myLineEdit` gives you a `QLineEdit *` which is actually a reference to that text box. So wherever you'd like to update UI, you should have that reference. For example if you're using TCP socket programming for contacting remote services, in `onReadyRead` signal of a `QTcpSocket`, you can update the text box with data you just received:

```
QLineEdit *textbox = ui->myLineEdit;
textbox->setText("updated data");
```